# Android screen sharing using WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc

I have heard about screen sharing on desktop using WebRTC. But for the Android, it seems not to have much information.

My question is:

1. Is it possible to use WebRTC for screen sharing on android?. I mean I can cast the current screen to the other phone's screen.
2. If 1 is Yes, How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wondering for a Native App or for Chrome/Firefox for Android?

Comment: @BenjaminTrent: Thanks for your reply. I mean the Native App. :)

Comment: Paul did you find any answer to your this question? Did you try the Android 5.0 which has MediaProjection API to enable android applications to capture screen?

Comment: @SojharoMangi: Sorry, I dont follow this project anymore. (This is my project in free time only)

Answer (score 8):

1. It is possible!
2. It can be done using the directions below.

I've used ScreenShareRTC in conjunction with ProjectRTC to stream the contents of the screen to a browser with decent quality and fairly low latency ~100ms.

I've added an example below that shows how to configure a screen share as a video source and add it as a track on a stream.

Get the VideoCapturer

```
@TargetApi(21)
private VideoCapturer createScreenCapturer() {
    if (mMediaProjectionPermissionResultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        report("User didn't give permission to capture the screen.");
        return null;
    }
    return new ScreenCapturerAndroid(
            mMediaProjectionPermissionResultData, new MediaProjection.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            report("User revoked permission to capture the screen.");
        }
    });
}
```

Initialize the capturer and add the tracks to the local media stream

```
private void initScreenCapturStream() {
    mLocalMediaStream = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
    MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxHeight", Integer.toString(mPeerConnParams.videoHeight)));
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxWidth", Integer.toString(mPeerConnParams.videoWidth)));
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxFrameRate", Integer.toString(mPeerConnParams.videoFps)));
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("minFrameRate", Integer.toString(mPeerConnParams.videoFps)));

    mVideoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer);
    videoCapturer.startCapture(mPeerConnParams.videoWidth, mPeerConnParams.videoHeight, mPeerConnParams.videoFps);
    VideoTrack localVideoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, mVideoSource);
    localVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
    mLocalMediaStream.addTrack(factory.createVideoTrack("ARDAMSv0", mVideoSource));
    AudioSource audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
    mLocalMediaStream.addTrack(factory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0", audioSource));

    mListener.onStatusChanged("STREAMING");
}
```

For more information this might be a good place to start.  Its a Android project that connects to a ProjectRTC signalling server and shares the screen as video.  I found it very helpful!

Android screen sharing project(Android client - Java)
https://github.com/Jeffiano/ScreenShareRTC

ProjectRTC(Node server)
https://github.com/pchab/ProjectRTC

Comment: Hi. is their any new latest github demo? the github link you added is very old and repo is not updated for years :(